# Einstein Split in Journey Builder Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein-analytics, einstein

I am trying to use Journey Builder to apply an Einstein Persona Split to my Journey Builder audience. This is a recurring email campaign that has been set up to be started from a triggered Automation. When I attempt to validate the Journey I am given the following error:

[image]

The client does not have Audience Builder provisioned in their account. Is this the issue?

Note: The client has had Einstein Analytics for almost a year, and when I navigate through their DEs I can see the Einstein MC Predictive Scores DE it refers to.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like the Data Extension is not attached to the Contact Model, you could try that, otherwise open a support ticket:)

Comment: thanks @Doug, I'll try this and let you know if it solves it or if we end up having to escalate the case.

Comment: @Doug, We had to engage SFMC support and they reviewed, saying it was setup correct but they had to "re-prime our contacts". So there you go... that was a first.

Comment: What exactly does re-prime contacts involve?;)

Answer (score 0):

When system created attributes are not linked or created properly in data designer, (MobileConnect has 3 instead of 30) a re-prime of the contact model has to occur. This error on when using an Einstein split identifies that this account needs a re-prime